# Import JavaScript after HTML is rendered in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In order to study the react framework, I've been developing a simple web application to rate books. It's currently looking like this:

[image]

And the idea of the side bar is simple enought: it's width will be 0 when hidden, and when I click a open menu button it will be set to another width.

The code behind it all is looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import home from '../../image/side-nav/home.png';
import list from '../../image/side-nav/list.png';
import '../../css/SideNavBar.css'
import * as utils from '../../scripts/utils.js'; 

const SideNavBar = () =>{
    return(
        <Router>
            <div>
                <span className="spanOpen" onClick={utils.openNav()}>&#9776;</span>
                <div className="sidenav">
                    <a className='closebtn' onClick={utils.closeNav()}>&times;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/'><img src={home} alt='Home' /><span className='h-item'>Home</span></Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/books'><img src={list} alt='Books' /><span className='b-item'>Books</span></Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className='sidenav-footer'>
                        <hr />
                        <small>Pelicer &copy; 2018</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
export default SideNavBar;
```

And here is the code of the `util.js` file, which contains the the fucntions to change:

```
export function openNav() {
    // document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")[0].style.width = "315px";
}

export function closeNav() {
    // document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")[0].style.width = "0";
}
```

But when I run it, I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`. It happens because it is trying to change the width of somethings that has not yet been created. What I want to do, and tried using `componentDidMount`, is to import the JavaScript after the HTML has been rendered, in a way that when it sets the width, the component is already there. Can someone help out in a solution?

Comment: Who's trying to change the width of something that has not been created?

Comment: My bad, @DragoşPaulMarinescu. I've eddited the question with aditional code.

Comment: I think you need to rethink how you show/hide the sidenav in a React-like approach. What you're doing now is vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `utils.xyz` functions too soon. This:

```
<span className="spanOpen" onClick={utils.openNav()}>&#9776;</span>
```

**calls** `utils.openNav` and uses its return value as the value of the `onClick`. You probably meant:

```
<span className="spanOpen" onClick={utils.openNav}>&#9776;</span>
```

(without the `()`) to just refer to the function. That will work **if** `utils.openNav` doesn't need `this` to refer to `utils` during the call. If it *does* need `this` to be `utils` during the call:

```
<span className="spanOpen" onClick={() => utils.openNav()}>&#9776;</span>
```

...which defines a function and uses that function as the value of `onClick`.

In that case where `this` matters, probably better to change that functional component to a class component, create that function once, and reuse it:

```
class SideNavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.openNav = () => utils.openNav();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

and then in `render`:

```
<span className="spanOpen" onClick={openNav}>&#9776;</span>
```

Comment: Actually, it would be better to do `onClick={utils.openNav}` (just removing the parenthesis) and not declaring a function in each render.

Comment: @FacundoMatteo: Only if `utils.openNav` doesn't care what `this` is when it's called. I chose not to make that assumption, but can clarify.

Comment: @FacundoMatteo: Did that now.

Comment: Thanks, @T.J.Crowder. I'll look into syntax a little more. And, as stated in other comments, try to 'think the react way' when trying to resolve problems like this one in the future.